# Problema al validar numeros enteros en C

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

En la función validar cuando ingreso primero una letra y después un numero me retorna 0 y se repite el bucle, pero cuando lo hago al contrario primero un numero y luego una letra no se repite y no me marca el printf de solo ingresar números, me gustaría que leyera toda la cadena y si encuentra una letra se repita así el primer carácter sea un numero o no.

```
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h> 
#include<string.h> 
#include<ctype.h> 
int validar(char[]) 
int main(){     
    char numero[100];       
    int i,Vector[20],a,b[20],n;                 
            for(i=0;i<3;i++){                                                       
                do{                             
                    printf("Ingrese un numero: ");
                    scanf("%s",numero);
                    n=validar(numero);
                    a=atoi(numero);                         
                    if(n==1){                                                                                           
                       b[i]=a;                                                      
                    }                                           
                    if(a<-10 || a>10)
                        printf("\n\nNo puede ser menor a -10 o mayor a 10\n\n");                                                                
                }while(n==0 || a<-10 || a>10);                                  
            }                                                                                                                   
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){               
            printf("%d ",b[i]);                         
        }                               
    getch();        
}   
int validar(char validar[100]){         
    int i;                          
    for(i=0;i<strlen(validar);i++){                         
        if(isdigit(validar[i])!=0 || validar[0]=='-' && validar[1]!='-')            
            return 1;                                                                                                               
        else{   
            printf("\nIngrese solo numeros\n\n");
            return 0;                           
        }           
    }               
}
```

Comment: `validar[1]!='-'` esta de mas. `isdigit(validar[i])!=0` tendria que ser solo `isdigit(validar[i])`. Puedes revisar si el primero es `-`. Si lo es que `i` tenga el valor inicial de `1`, sino que tenga el valor inicial de `0`. Asi en el loop solo revisas que `isdigit(validar[i])`

Answer (score 0):

Tu código no compila porque tienes varios errores. Este código realiza la validación de una manera similar a la que tienes en tu código, pero comprueba además si el dato entrado es una cadena vacía.

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <ctype.h> 

bool validar(const char input[])
{
    if (!input)
        return false;
    
    int idx = 0;
    for (; input[idx] != '\0'; idx++) {
        char c = input[idx];
        
        if (!isdigit(c) && ((idx > 0) || (c != '-')))
            return false;
    }
    
    return (idx > 0);
}

int main()
{
    char const *inputs[] = {
        "123",
        "Abcc",
        "-123",
        "k123",
        "123h",
        "1-23"
    };
    
    for (int idx = 0; idx < sizeof(inputs)/sizeof(inputs[0]); idx++) {
        if (validar(inputs[idx])) {
            printf( "%s es un número correcto\n", inputs[idx] );
        }
        else {
            printf( "%s NO es un número correcto\n", inputs[idx] );
        }
    }
}
```

Otra manera de implementar el chequeo de la entrada es utilizando la función `strtol()` como en este código que pongo aquí. Utilizando esta función puedes hacer a la vez la validación de la entrada y la conversión.

```
bool validar(const char input[])
{
    char *endp;
    
    if ((input != NULL) && (input[0] != '\0')) {
        strtol(input, &endp, 0);
        return *endp == '\0';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```